# CPU throttle / governor / fan

Tags: release-loki

Is it possible to change the CPU throttling and governor in Loki? I have Elementary OS installed on a separate partition on my Windows 10 machine SSD drive. I have Chrome and Firefox and Thunderbird installed and nothing else and my fan is always kicking on and the laptop actually runs much hotter than when booted into Windows. Is it possible to adjust the CPU throttling or maybe change the governor type and settings at the kernel level? With only 3 applications installed, the fan is always kicking on regardless of whether I'm using it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can either by configuring it through the terminal via

```
sudo apt-get install cpufrequtils
sudo cpufreq-set -r -g performance **or whatever you want to set it too (powersave, ondemand, etc)
```

Or you can configure it through TLP if you have that installed. Instructions on that can be found here http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

The Linux Thermal daemon might also be interesting to try:
https://01.org/linux-thermal-daemon/documentation/introduction-thermal-daemon
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/ThermalIssues

Installation:

```
sudo apt install thermald
```